# How to find the "href" of the last <tr> element?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X39od.jpg)I am trying to get the "href" of a particular frame which you can find in the image , i tried as much as i can but i am not able to get the "href"

```
List<WebElement> list=d.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[52]/td"));

                   for(WebElement e : list){
                       String link = e.getAttribute("href");
                      System.out.println(link);
```

I tried the above code , i took the Xpath of that frame and tried to get the href of that frame . Link: "https://iaeme.com/ijciet/issues.asp?VType=8&IType=10&JType=IJCIET&PageNumber=1"

Comment: of which link you are trying to get href from the given page?

Comment: Please check the image buddy link : "https://iaeme.com/ijciet/issues.asp?VType=8&IType=10&JType=IJCIET&PageNumber=1" , In this link the page number frame at the bottom .

Comment: use this //*[contains(@linktext,'issues.asp?VType=8&IType=10&JType=IJCIET&PageNumber="+n+"')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `xpath` you shared to get all the "href" attributes you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> list = d.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@name='form1']/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td/a"));
    for(WebElement e : list)
        System.out.println(e.getAttribute("href"));
```

Comment: I want to know how did u generate the xpath which you used List<WebElement> list = d.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@name='form1']/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td/a"));

Comment: i need help on similar problem , i want to know the xpath of the page number frame of this link , http://freevideolectures.com/Subject/Mathematics/VideoCourses/Page5 , Pls construct and give me .