# How to identify the second last check box?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I used to write like `//button[@class='button'][last()-1]` Is it correct or are there any other techniques?

Answer (score -1):

In case of varying number  of *check boxes*, to identify the second last *check box* you can use the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) predicates `last()`, `[last()-1]`, etc as well.

As an example the following are valid **xpath**:

- `/bookstore/book[last()]`
- `/bookstore/book[last()-1]`
- `/bookstore/book[last()-2]`

---

### Conclusion

Syntactically **`//button[@class='button'][last()-1]`** is a valid *xpath*.

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Python Selenium - How can I click on the third last element from a group of elements in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318738/python-selenium-how-can-i-click-on-the-third-last-element-from-a-group-of-elem/53319740#53319740)

---

### Reference

- [How to find the “href” of the last  element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305697/how-to-find-the-href-of-the-last-tr-element/47306504#47306504)
- [Getting text from the last hyperlink tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319723/getting-text-from-the-last-hyperlink-tag/48319872#48319872)
- Python Selenium - How to loop to the last

  element in a site